# Commenting blocks in Eclipse on Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, comments

How do I comment blocks of code in Eclipse on a Mac?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Command (the clover/apple key next to the space bar) forward slash (/)

Comment: It appears this has been changed to avoid conflict with the help shortcut in OSX, and the answer is now, as @PawelPros noted below, ctrl+command+/ to comment, ctrl+command+\ to uncomment.

Answer (score 18):

Apple + Shift + / will toggle a block of selected code using  /* */
Apple + / will toggle a line (or multiple, if selected) using //

You may have to disable the OS hotkey (apple + shift + / brings up the help menu)

Comment: How to disable the OS hotkey in Mac ?

Comment: @user1182253 Goto your Mac Settings application -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts/Hot Keys -> Applications shorcuts -> disable "show help menu"
Sorry if there are some mistakes in the menu labels, my mac os is not in english.

Comment: Unfortunately, even with this, it won't work for xml code comments/uncomments.

Comment: Thank you! Just started using Android studio and I use `Cmd` + `Shift` + `/` in every other editor for comments, but this was just bringing up the help menu.

Comment: @Marcus, I believe you cannot use /* */ style comments for XML.  You should use <!--  --> style instead.

Comment: @briggsm Right, my only point is that there aren't shortcuts for commenting blocks in xml.

Comment: For me on Yosemite, on STS 3.6.4, the keys for block comments are `Cmd` + `Ctrl` + `/`

Answer (score 18):

Ctrl + cmd + / <- block comment
and
Ctrol + cmd + \ <- remove comment

Answer (score 2):

`Command` + `/` comments the selection.

Answer (score 0):

select the text that you want to put as a comment and use 
'`command` + `/`' to apply multi line comment with each line having '`//`'

However If you use 
'`command` + `control` + `/`' will have the text commented with '`/* ... */`' at the beginning and end which is much better than the previous one

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer:

select the text that you want to put as a comment and use

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

### Long Answer:

**Single line**

Toggle of same keys

*comment* <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

*uncomment* <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

**Multiline**

*comment* <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

*uncomment* <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> (note the backslash)

**For an Exact List of all Shortcuts or if you want to change some look at:**

*Eclipce->Settings->General->Keys*

Answer (score 0):

For multiple line comments i.e /*. code. */

```
Command + control + /
```

OR

For Single line comments i.e //

```
Command + /
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Keyboard shortcuts for commenting & uncommenting code on Mac.

Shortcuts for commenting the code :

- `/*...*/` (Multi-line comment) : <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Control ^</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>
- `//` (Single-line comment) : <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Shortcuts for un-commenting the code :

- Press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to uncomment a selected single-line comment.
- Press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Control ^</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> to uncomment a selected multi-line comment.

Answer (score 0):

Select the text that you want to put as a comment and use 'command + /'

Answer (score 0):

Remove toggle comments in eclipse.

command + shift + 7